# Remotely starting a screen session through ssh and closing the ssh session immediately

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

My goal is to remote to a server through ssh, start a screen, start a script, let the script run, and exit the ssh session while keeping the screen running its own python script. This is what I have:

```
ssh -t myuser@hostname screen python somepath.py -s 'potato'
```

The problem with this is, after I run it, I have to manually ctrl + a + d, and exit out of the ssh session myself. Is there a way to do it all in one go without needing human interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `-d -m` to the screen command. remove `-t`

Try this:

```
ssh myuser@hostname screen -d -m python somepath.py
```